# document is not defined in main.ts to run "webpack --mode development"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I've tried this comment "webpack --mode development" to run of this code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

in the src/main.ts --- 
I got this error...

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ^
  ReferenceError: document is not defined

  - main.ts:95362 Object../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main.ts
    /home/glad/Documents/glpdesktop-ang/src/main.ts:95362:1

  - main.ts:21 __webpack_require__
    /home/glad/Documents/glpdesktop-ang/src/main.ts:21:30

  - main.ts:70
    /home/glad/Documents/glpdesktop-ang/src/main.ts:70:18

  - main.ts:73
    /home/glad/Documents/glpdesktop-ang/src/main.ts:73:10

  - index.js:247 HtmlWebpackPlugin.evaluateCompilationResult
    [glpdesktop-ang]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:247:28

  - index.js:161 Promise.resolve.then.then.then.compiledTemplate
    [glpdesktop-ang]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:161:23


  - next_tick.js:188 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem?
 Thanks ...

Comment: Try `window.document.addEventListener(....`

Comment: tried but same thing...
showing "window is not defined"

Comment: Why do you try to bootstrap angular app inside document.addEventListener? Simply use `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Comment: `document` and `window` are only defined in the browser, so looks like webpack tries to access them when compiling the code. I pasted `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});` into both of my Angular apps (v5, one with Angular CLI, one without - but with custom Webpack configuration) and had no issues with compilation in both of them.

Comment: the simplest solution is to stop bootstrapping the application inside event handler - unless you have a reason for it

Comment: Actually Em following ng-universal Doc,

Comment: Actually Em following ng-universal Doc simply, and when I try to bind it to my project it's happening like this,
I did not write extra anything and this main.ts file has created, at time of generating angular universal with my project.
Hope you understand my point and em trying to find this solution but till not get anything for it..
and thank you for your reply.

Comment: I haven't used ng-universal. I am out of ideas. If you follow their guide and experience this problem, open an issue on their github account.